# Strange behaviour while accessing an array with SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, iterator, simplexml

I'm parsing a Webserivce response and I have a strange behaviour,

Here's a small example of [what returns me the WS](http://pastie.org/private/18wq4kezadyfsuroy3x9og)

The output is done with `var_dump($results);`

But If I do `var_dump($results->channel->item);` **instead of having an array with 9 elements in it**, [I have this](http://pastie.org/private/1kzcjtquoomimu0rboruw) which seems to be the 1 element of the array.

What is that behaviour ?
Thanks.

PS: I run on PHP 5.4.6 and Xdebug 2.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is completely normal. `$results->channel->item` is an iterator, it is meant to be used in a `foreach` loop. This will get you all `item` elements:

```
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    var_dump($item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, well, difficult to guess that it's an iterator because xdebug says to us it's an "array".

Comment: @Tristan Yes it's impossible to guess, that's why it is important to refer to the documentation [SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) where the class definition is `SimpleXMLElement implements Traversable.`